# Obtaining the value from any key-value from a string representation of a json in Scala (using scala.util.parsing.json)

Tags: json, scala, parsing

Imagine I have a json (in string format) that looked like:

```
val jsonString: String = "
    {
      "toys": {
        "orange toys": {
           "brand":"Toys-R-Us",
           "price":"123.45"
         } 
      },
      "date":"05-27-1996" 
    }
"
```

My question is, how can I get the value for "brand" (Toys-R-Us), in Scala, using the `scala.util.parsing.json` library? I am assuming that this might require the traversing of the json or maybe even easier, a way to look up the key "brand" and from their obtaining the value.

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` is deprecated and removed in newer versions of the stdlib, use any of the open source libraries like **circe**, **play-json**, **ujson**, **json4s**, **jsonitter-scala**, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scala.util.parsing.json` library is outdated, unsafe for open systems, and not included in the latest version of the Scala library.

Use [dijon](https://github.com/jvican/dijon) FTW!

```
import dijon._
import scala.language.dynamics._

val jsonString: String = """
    {
      "toys": {
        "orange toys": {
           "brand":"Toys-R-Us",
           "price":"123.45"
         } 
      },
      "date":"05-27-1996" 
    }
"""

println(parse(jsonString).toys.`orange toys`.brand)
```

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/U8gJdkrUSkqh7r7VgGWhzg) is a runnable code on Scastie that works fine with Scala 2 and Scala 3.

Comment: I took your approach. It is fair and works nicely. Thank you for sharing.